# column selection by value between DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, selection, multiple-columns

I have some problem of column selection between DataFrames.

```
from pandas import DataFrame, concat

d1 = {'name': ['C', 'B'],
     'age': [10, 15],
    }

d2 = {'name': ['C', 'A', 'B'],
     'age': [10, 30, 15],
     'married': [False, True, False]
    }

df1 = DataFrame(d1)
df2 = DataFrame(d2)
```

But I want this.

```
  name  age  married
0    C   10    False
2    B   15    False
```

Plz. help me. Thanks.

Comment: Data frame for df2 returns almost same that you want. Could you clarify what is not right with  these data frames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is called merge. So use `df1.merge(df2)`

Output :

```
   age name  married
0   10    C    False
1   15    B    False
```

Comment: thank you, @Bharath shetty but if df1 has lesser rows than df2, how can I have the same result?

Comment: @mack I suggested you accept this answer , since this is cover all you need ~ :-)

Comment: I failed to find the edit button.
from pandas import DataFrame, concat

d1 = {'name': ['C', 'B'],
     'age': [10, 15],
    }

d2 = {'name': ['C', 'A', 'B'],
     'age': [10, 30, 15],
     'married': [False, True, False]
    }
and I want to get the same result.
thank you for helping me.

Comment: It will return the same result. The edit is below th tags in case you are looking

Comment: Thank you @Bharath shetty
so kind of you

Answer (score 1):

Also, try `isin`

```
df2.loc[df2.name.isin(df1.name),:]
```

Comment: There is `df1['age'] == df2['age']` so not a good sol  I think

Comment: @Bharathshetty I think he is doing the filter from df2 by using df1

Comment: @mack then doing the isin is not hurt ~ :-)